# Linq Query If Field Is In An Array?

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

The code below is incorrect but the idea here is that I want to grab values from "SqlTable" where the value for "Field" is inside of "Array[]".

```
var Result =
    from a in SqlTable
    where a.Field is in Array[]
    select a;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Queryable.Contains Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641.aspx):

```
var result =
    from a in mySqlTable
    where myArray.Contains(a.Field)
    select a;
```

See also: [Creating IN Queries With Linq To Sql](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/)

Comment: or "where Array.IndexOf(myArray, a.Field) > -1"

Comment: @Floyd: That works if you use LINQ-to-Objects, but I'm not sure if it does when you use LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: @msarchet: See mscorlib.dll - "bool IList.Contains(object value)
        {
            return Array.IndexOf(this, value) >= GetLowerBound(0);
        }
" -This is the Framework-Implementation for Array.Contains(..). But its true, its not so beautiful as "myArray.Contains(a.Field)".

Comment: @Floyd I understand that `myArray.Contains(a.Field)` is just an abstraction of something much more complex. I was talking more from a readability standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming now that Field and Array[] contains values that has a equality operator in place, and that the A. Then you can write it like this:

```
var Result =
    from a in SqlTable
    where Array[].Any( ae => ae == a.Field)
    select a;
```

Comment: Will Any really be that much slower than Contains?

Comment: I think, because Contians use Array.IndexOf and this interate the array and compare with equals. Any interates the array and execute the delegeate.